# Are there luggage storage lockers inside Panama City Airport, Panama?

Tags: luggage-storage, pty

Are there lockers to store luggage inside Panama City Airport (*Aeropuerto Internacional de Tocumen*, PTY)?

I can't find information about any but there is one rather old forum post that says there is. Other Google hits for lockers in PTY don't yield any information about them.

If there are any, where are they located and how much do they charge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cooperativa de Trabajo/RL Cooptram](http://www.maleterosdepanama.com/index.php/productos-y-servicios/custodia-de-equipajes) is located in the lower level of Panama's Tocumen International Airport (PTY):

> (507) 238-3143
>   `info@cooptramrl.com`
>   Storage fees for services (24 hours):
>
> ```
> Suitcases   US $ 5.00 per unit
> Boxes       US $ 6.00 per unit
> Surfboards  US $ 8.00 per unit
> TV          US $ 8.00 per unit
> Others      US $ 8.00 per unit
> ```
>
> You can also request a locker for small items. This costs US $ 10.00
>
> Note: These costs are charged per day and will have a [time limit] of three months [before removal].

Per [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294480-i1194-k8622167-Tocumen_airport_any_luggage_storage_facility-Panama_City_Panama_Province.html) *to the right once you get out of Customs.*
Map [here](http://www.tocumenpanama.aero/images/mapas/nivel100/) (*Consigna de Equipaje* icon).

Answer (score 2):

If you have (or pay for) access to the Copa VIP lounge, there is an area inside under camera, along with four keyed storage lockers, you can leave your luggage for short periods of time. The service is included with the cost of access to the lounge

Comment: It would help if you could be more specific than "a short time". Minutes? Hours? A couple of days?

Answer (score 1):

I've used it before. Once you clear customs and walk 'out' of the queues, it will be to your right hand side. It seems to be a pretty casual security situation. While I think the staff are honest, retrieving my bags was no more than pointing out which were mine and handing over the money without a close verification of the receipt. I wouldn't store anything of great value there.

Answer (score -2):

I did some research on the internet as I had the same problem and I found a blog post here: https://snoopy-alien.com/2017/12/12/luggage-storage-in-panama-city/

To me it was a better way to storage my luggage in Panama City 'cause I didn't want to go back to the airport to pick up my suitcases. Maybe it would be helpful for you.

Comment: Welcome to Travel! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.