# Are there in 2023 still luggage storage lockers inside Panama City Airport, Panama?

Tags: luggage-storage, pty

I am trying to find out what the luggage storage options are at Panama City Airport (PTY) in Panama. Searching leads me to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88448/are-there-luggage-storage-lockers-inside-panama-city-airport-panama), which is exactly what I am looking for but it is 6 years old and the link and e-mail referenced in the answer don't work anymore. Interestingly, searching in Spanish leads to [this website](https://respuestas.me/q/hay-casilleros-para-guardar-equipaje-dentro-del-aeropuerto-de-la-ciudad-de-33748217800), which seems to be a Spanish translation of Travel Stackexchange (?) with the very same answer in English.

[This](https://panamatocumen.com/en/faqs#equipaje) self-described "non-official" airport website says:

*Luggage storage is available in the airport's customs area.*

Which is too vague for me to rely on.

Does anyone have any idea if the same luggage storage options still exist?

Comment: There is an [official Tocumen Airport page](http://tocumenpanama.aero). I don't speak Spanish; using Google Chrome to translate, there is no mention of luggage storage. There is, however, a [Contact Us page](http://tocumenpanama.aero/index.php/contactenos) with both a telephone and an email address. Ask the airport directly.

Comment: Thanks, I sent them an email and got an answer - will post below.

Comment: Did you have success using/locating luggage storage in Tocumen? We have a trip coming up & got about as far as you did online! Any feedback appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By e-mail the Tocumen staff told me that there is indeed a luggage storage at the airport. It's at the first floor and called Consigna de Equipajes. Pricing and other details are available in-person, not online, as far as I can figure out. But at least there are options available.